# get the size of std::array inside unique_ptr without an instance in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, stdarray

I have a type declared as:

```
using Buffer = std::unique_ptr<std::array<uint8_t, N>>;
```

I also have a template function declared as:

```
template<typename Buffer>
bool temp_func()
{
    // do something
}
```

and I'm calling temp_func with type Buffer:

```
temp_func<Buffer>();
```

now, inside temp_func I want to get the size of the type `Buffer` without creating an instance of this type.

what I need is something similar to `std::tuple_size<Buffer>::value` except I can't call `std::tuple_size` on `unique_ptr`, only directly on `std::array`.

I can use C++11 only. How can I do it?

Comment: Whats is `N` in your declaration?

Comment: `Buffer::element_type` would be your array type.  And `std::tuple_size` would work on that type.

Comment: "_I want to get the size of the type Buffer_": What size exactly do you want to have? The size of `Buffer` (i.e. `std::unique_ptr<std::array<uint8_t, N>>`), the size of `std::array<uint8_t, N>` or the value `N`? These are all different things and your question seems to imply all three at different places.

Comment: There's probably something convoluted you could do with `sizeof` and [std::declval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) but it might be better if you define an alias for the intermediate type `std::array<uint8_t, N>`, and then have `using Buffer = std::unique_ptr<Intermediate_t>;`

Comment: @tkausl `array::size()` is nonstatic, so it requires an instance. Instead, you can use `std::tuple_size<typename Buffer::element_type>::value`.

Comment: `N` is hard coded unsigned value: `std::size_t N = 50000U`. I want to get back `N`

Answer (score 10):

Use [`std::unique_ptr::element_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to access the contained array type, then apply `std::tuple_size` as you normally would.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

constexpr std::size_t N{10};

using Buffer = std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::uint8_t, N>>;

static_assert(std::tuple_size<Buffer::element_type>::value == N, "error");
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/74bz1TzEW).

In C++17 or above, you can substitute `std::tuple_size<T>::value` with `std::tuple_size_v<T>` for added conciseness:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

constexpr std::size_t N{10};

using Buffer = std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::uint8_t, N>>;

static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<Buffer::element_type> == N);
```

Comment: what if mu Buffer is not declaring directly as `using Buffer = std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::uint8_t, N>>;`. instead, I have a template class `BufferContatiner` that wrap a container of the template type. and Buffer declared as `using Buffer = std::unique_ptr<BufferContainer<rstd::array<std::uint8_t, N>>>;`.

Comment: @אנונימי `BufferContainer` would need to expose it's underlying array type. E.g. define a member type like `BufferContainer::array_type`. Then just proceed in the same way: `std::tuple_size<Buffer::element_type::array_type>::value`

Comment: Or better yet, expose `N` directly from `BufferContainer`

Comment: worked for me, except I had to add `typename`: std::tuple_size<typename Buffer::element_type::array_type>::value`. can you explain to me why?

Comment: @אנונימי `typename` is needed for [dependent types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name). Whether that expression has dependent types depends on where the names are coming from. For example, if your [use case looks like this](https://godbolt.org/z/TnhcPrYMn), `typename` isn't required.

Answer (score 3):

You can use partial specialization to define a trait that gets `N` from `Buffer`. I assume the element type is always `uint8_t`. Then this works in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>


template <typename T> struct size_of_unique_uint8_t_array;

template <size_t N>
struct size_of_unique_uint8_t_array<std::unique_ptr<std::array<uint8_t,N>>> {
    static constexpr size_t value = N;
};


int main()
{
    using Buffer = std::unique_ptr<std::array<uint8_t, 42>>;
    std::cout << size_of_unique_uint8_t_array<Buffer>::value;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8WzaYE8n8)